# Generating a table with jQuery with XML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, html-table

I am new to jQuery, and js for that matter. I am trying to create a table from XML data, but I can't get the output correct. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<table id="daily_fruit">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
var xml = '<daily_fruit><day>Mon</day><type>apple</type><day>Tues</day><type>orange</type><day>Wed</day><type>banana</type><day>Thur</day><type>pear</type></daily_fruit>';

xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
  $xml = $(xmlDoc);
$($xml).each(function() {

  var showTimes = $xml.find('daily_fruit').each(function() {
    var $day = $(this).find('day').text();
    var $type = $(this).find("type").text();

    $("#daily_fruit").find('tbody')
      .append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')
          .append($day))
      )
      .append($('<td>')
        .append($type))
  });
});
```

Current Output:

```
MonTuesWedThur
appleorangebananapear
```

Desired Output:

```
Mon  apple
Tues orange
Wed  banana
Thur pear
```

I think I am close, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your XML so that each fruit is within its own tag. Then instead of finding the "daily_fruit" tag for your each loop, use the "fruit" tag.

Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/57wgab88/

```
var xml = '<daily_fruit><fruit><day>Mon</day><type>apple</type></fruit><fruit><day>Tues</day><type>orange</type></fruit><fruit><day>Wed</day><type>banana</type></fruit><fruit><day>Thur</day><type>pear</type></fruit></daily_fruit>';

xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
  $xml = $(xmlDoc);
$($xml).each(function() {

  var showTimes = $xml.find('fruit').each(function() {
    var $day = $(this).find('day').text();
    var $type = $(this).find("type").text();
    $("#daily_fruit").find('tbody')
      .append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')
          .append($day))
        .append($('<td>')
          .append($type))
      )
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! - This is a simple and elegant answer. As long as I have the ability to modify the XML data, which in this case, I do. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Given such XML structure, you're supposed to iterate through `<day>` elements instead. Assuming that each `<day>` is always followed by corresponding `<type>` element :

```js
var xml = '<daily_fruit><day>Mon</day><type>apple</type><day>Tues</day><type>orange</type><day>Wed</day><type>banana</type><day>Thur</day><type>pear</type></daily_fruit>';

xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
  $xml = $(xmlDoc);
$($xml).each(function() {

   var showTimes = $xml.find('day').each(function() {
    var $day = $(this).text();
    var $type = $(this).next("type").text();
    $("#daily_fruit").find('tbody')
      .append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')
          .append($day))
        .append($('<td>')
          .append($type))
      )
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="daily_fruit">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```